# When we substitute variables do we compose functions?

Tags: functions, notation, change-of-variable

Suppose that we have the function $f(u)=2u+3$ and we define $u=2x$. What of the below expressions are correct?
$$f(u(x))=4x+3 \ \text{or} \ f(x)=4x+3 $$

Does the "definition" serves only as a substitution (shorthand) i.e. is "$f$" still the same function or the composition of $f \circ u$ irrespective of the fact that we didn't write $u(x)=2x$ at first (abuse of notation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second of your suggestions is the correct interpretation. We often abuse notation and write $f(x)$, although one actually defines a new function by composition $\hat f(x)=f\circ u(x)$. The most common application is the substitution, when calculating integrals. The error *cancels* in the end of those calculations by resubstitution (for indefinite integrals) or because you also substitute the boundaries (for definite integrals).

Comment: So it would be better to write $f'(x)=f(u(x))$? We need the symbol $f'$ because in general these two functions won't have the same domain which is necessary condition for two functions to be equal?

Comment: Maybe you should not use $f'$, because it could be confused with the derivative - but choosing a different symbol after substituting variables if you want to be mathematically precise would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The **first** of your suggestions is correct:
$f(u(x)) = 2u(x) + 3 = 2(2x) + 3 = 4x + 3$.

The second is incorrect, since $f(x) = 2x + 3$.

However, it is common, especially in physics, to abuse notation and write $f(x) = 4x+3$.

Comment: You are of course right, if you mean the first equation. I meant the second sentence - implying that $f(x)=4x+3$ is an abuse of notation, though.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, what notation you use is irrelevant as long as you know what you are doing. If you are just a beginner it's best to go with the standard notation of $$f(u(x))=4x+3 $$

To me the expression above reads: In $f(x)$ if I feed in the function $u(x)$'s output as an input then I have the algebraic expression $4x+3$ denoted as $ f(u(x))$ but perhaps you could understand the same thing if it was written as $f(x)$. Being attentive to notation is only important when you're talking to someone else haha

Answer (score 0):

We consider two functions $f$ and $g$:
\begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}&\qquad &g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&f(u)=2u+3&\qquad &g(u)=4u+3\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Here we have two linear real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ which are different, since e.g. $f(1)\ne g(1)$.

A substitution $u=2x$ in $f$ and $g$ is a composition of functions with a function $u$:
\begin{align*}
&u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&u(x)=2x
\end{align*}
We obtain
\begin{align*}
&f\circ u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}&\qquad &g\circ u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&f(u(x))=f(2x)=4x+3&\qquad &g(u(x))=g(2x)=8x+3\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}

> - We see from (1) and (2) that $f(2x)=g(x)$ is an identity.
> - But setting $f(x)=g(x)$ is just an equation which is true iff $2x+3=4x+3$, i.e. $x=0$.